# Language files and translation in EE 3

Tags: language

i'm trying to change the names of the months from english to greek language in EE3... is there any file that i can modify somewhere in the installation?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify the languages used by EE using [language packs](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/general/languages.html).  However there does not (yet) appear to be a Greek language pack.  The language packs are open-source and so you maybe can contribute a suitable pack for Greek to the shared activity - it is located on the Ellis Labs' [Github](https://github.com/EllisLab) pages.  There are also tools you can use to help with the translation of core elements of the EE system - more details [here](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/cp/utilities/translate/index.html).

HTH